# notation for restriction on x

Tags: notation

For my thesis I need to describe 'mixture data'. This is data of which each sample consists of a mixture of all variables, with the sum of the values of each variable is 1 or 100%.

An example: when mixing paint, say red paint is $x_1$, blue is $x_2$, yellow is $x_3$, etc. To describe the resulting mix, you need to assign values to each $x_i$ and the values should be positive and sum to 1. for example $x_1=0.2$, $x_2=0.2$ and $x_3=0.6$ if mixing 3 paints. It all should follow:

1. $0 \le x_i \le1$
2. i = 1, 2, 3, ..., n
3. $\sum x_i = 1$

My question is, how should I note this down properly readable and short as possible in one 'sentence'? A list of a few solutions where readability is exchanged for shortness and visa versa would be pretty perfect.

The best I've got now is: $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 1$, where $0 \le x_i$. (I think the $x_i \le 1$ part can be omitted.)
However, I was wondering if there is a better mathematical notation for it. I have found the *for all* symbol ($\forall$) but I am not sure how I should use this and if I could (and should) use it here.

Note: if this still isn't obvious: I am *not* a mathematician. :)

Comment: What you want is close to being [convex combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination).

Comment: Thanks! I'll sure look into that. I see that it even links to mixture distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the $\forall$ symbol, you could write it like this:
$$\left\{x_i; i\in\{1,...,n\}; \sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i=1;\forall i\in\{1,..n\}\ x_i\geq 0\right\}.$$

But just remember that, in general, being understood is more important than finding the most concise mathematical notation in the world.

Comment: I'll accept yours, just because of the reminder of the importance of being understood. I was thinking to lose the the word 'where', but I realized that  (ironically) for the chemists who need to read my report

"$\sum_{i=1}^n xi=1$, where $xi \ge 0$"

is probably less dazzling than both of your solutions where everything is spelled out.

For a chemist, the headache starts when he encounters a formula and the size of the headache is proportional to the length of the formula, and nothing can change that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion not that strict:

$\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 1$, and $x_i \ge 0\, \forall i \in \{1,2,...n\}$